# How to change size of a control through animation?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I want to change the size of a control through animation, which looks like 3D Touch animation on iOS(not just ScaleAnimation, I want to change the length and width of it separately), and then attach the animation to the control.

I have tried to search for documents of *Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations* namespace but find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to search for documents of Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations namespace but find nothing.

Microsoft.Toolkit contains **AnimationExtensions** Scale method could be used to scale element, you could refer to document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/scale).

You could also use a natural motion composition animation on a uielement. For more detail please refer to xaml controls gallery app.

**For Example**

```
Compositor _compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation _springAnimation;

private void CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(float finalValue)
{
    if (_springAnimation == null)
    {
        _springAnimation = _compositor.CreateSpringVector3Animation();
        _springAnimation.Target = "Scale";
    }

    _springAnimation.FinalValue = new Vector3(finalValue);
}

private void element_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Scale up to 1.5
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.5f);

    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
}

private void element_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Scale back down to 1.0
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.0f);

    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it seems that it is no longer provided in NuGet package, and this code looks length and width are magnified by the same multiple.

What I need is not the same multiple, If getting older version could solve this, I want to know  the correct version.

Comment: It is aviable in WindowsCommunityToolkit version [6.1.1](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/6.1.1/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/Extensions/AnimationExtensions.Scale.cs)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this version is too old for me to develop other visual effects. Recently I found Storyboard in *System.Windows.Media.Animation* , can it meet my requirement?

Comment: Sure, you could use double animation to animatie Scale property like WindowsCommunityToolkit  [did](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/6.1.1/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/Extensions/AnimationExtensions.Scale.cs#L91) .